# How can i get the absolute path by the file struct in FreeBSD?

Tags: c, kernel, freebsd

I'm studying the FreeBSD file system, and I'm trying to write a simple hook.

In Linux, I can simply get the absolute path information with the `d_path()` function.

I can get the registered file struct in FreeBSD kernel, so how can I get the absolute path?